# Google charts, no puedo usar variables en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-chart-api

Tengo una query que me trae de SQL una lista de Nombres con sus respectivos campos (On Time & Delayed).

La query la traigo con PHP y si tiro un `echo $datosGrafico`; me devuelve esto:

```
['Agustin', 17, 1 ],
['Andrea', 79, 0 ],
['Carla', 17, 0 ],
['Cecilia', 6, 0 ],
['Denise', 0, 0 ],
['Diego', 3, 0 ],
['Ezequiel', 0, 0 ],
['German', 0, 0 ]
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, el problema surge cuando intento meter ese echo en el  script de abajo, deja de funcionar el google charts:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:["bar"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);
        function drawStuff() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'],
            //(La variable $datosGrafico DEBERIA IR ACA en lugar de meter uno a uno a mano)

            ['Agustin', 17, 1],
            ['Lucas', 6, 2], 
            ]);

            var options = {
            width: 425,
            height: 450,
            chart: {
                title: 'Spread of SLAs by Analist',
                subtitle: 'Amount of Tickets'
            },
            bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
            }
            ;

            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 300px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
```

Alguna idea porque?

Comment: ¿No tienes ningun error de javascript en la consola?

Answer (score 1):

Esta lína parece ser la que da problemas;

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["bar"]});
```

No soy muy experto en la API de Google Charts pero he echado un vistazo al ejemplo que tienen en su documentación y aparentemente necesitas pasarle otro parametro a packages;

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
```

**UPDATE:** Prueba si esto te funciona porque el problema tambien creo que es que tratas de usar una variable de PHP en JavaScript directamente. La variable  $datosGrafico creo que debe de ser un array bidimensional en PHP.

```
//En PHP
$datosGrafico = array(
    array('Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'),
    array('Agustin', 17, 1 ),
    array('Andrea', 79, 0 ),
    array('Carla', 17, 0 ),
    array('Cecilia', 6, 0 ),
    array('Denise', 0, 0 ),
    array('Diego', 3, 0 ),
    array('Ezequiel', 0, 0 ),
    array('German', 0, 0 )
);
```

Luego obtienes los datos de la variable de PHP en una de JavaScript de la siguiente forma:

```
 function drawStuff() {

//Al inicio de la funcion haz:
var datosGrafico = <?php echo json_encode($datosGrafico); ?>;

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datosGrafico);
```

No lo he probado pero es lo que deduzco dado que esto si funciona:

```
    // Array bidimensional en JavaScript

    var datosGrafico = [
     ['Analista', 'On Time', 'Delayed'],
     ['Agustin', 17, 1 ],
     ['Andrea', 79, 0 ],
     ['Carla', 17, 0 ],
     ['Cecilia', 6, 0 ],
     ['Denise', 0, 0 ],
     ['Diego', 3, 0 ],
     ['Ezequiel', 0, 0 ],
     ['German', 0, 0 ]
   ];

   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datosGrafico);
```

Comment: Gracias Serux, pero tampoco funciono. Otra que se me ocurrió es pasarle la cadena guardada en la variable de PHP a travez de una variable de java, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Debe de haber algún problema que se me escapa porque he puesto en el ejemplo la salida tal cual te la da php. ¿ Puedes poner en tu pregunta la manera en la que haces el echo de php ?

Comment: Echale un vistazo al update de mi respuesta porque por lo que parece no funciona si le pasas  los datos en forma de cadena. Ahora probare si funciona siendo datosGrafico un array .

Comment: Intenta probar lo que acabo de poner en el update , es lo único que se me ocurre .